# Python unittest and assert method

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I've been reading online that Python's unittest does not include the assert command, and you can only get it from pytest.  And, that with unittest you can only use the methods like assertEqual and assertTrue, etc...  However, I have been able to use assert all by itself in unittest without importing pytest with only an import unittest line at the top of my code.

assert x==1

This works fine.  Has unittest now incorporated this into its own framework?  I have not see it in the docs.  I had previously installed pytest on my machine, but am not importing it directly into the module.  Is it that it's somehow picking up the pytest methods just with the import unittest line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been reading online that Python's unittest does not include the assert command, and you can only get it from pytest.

`assert` is part of the language. You don't have to get it from anywhere.

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.1 (default, Apr  4 2020, 07:35:43) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> assert True==False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>>
```